# Ghost error: Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, uiwindow, symbolicatecrash

I have a great problem with my app, I have update it to iOS 9 with Xcode 7 GM, and i have tested it with all my devices, with no error or crash.
I have submitted to the App Store but all my user have reported that when they open the app, crash immediately, I have checked the crash log that I have with QuincyKit, and say this:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch'
```

I have checked everything, and i have found that in iOS all `UIWindow` must have a `rootViewController` setted, so i have checked in all my project and I have found that I have a 3rd party library: `WTStatusBar` that doesn't set the `rootviewcontroller`, so I have do this fix:

```
UIViewController* vc = [[UIViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    self.rootViewController = vc;
```

for work around, and then i do this:

```
NSArray *windows = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows];
for(UIWindow *window in windows) {
    NSLog(@"window: %@",window.description);
    if(window.rootViewController == nil){
        UIViewController* vc = [[UIViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        window.rootViewController = vc;
    }
}
```

to check if there is some `UIWindow` not setted, and now there isn't I have submitted the update to apple and I request an expedited review, that they give me, the update go live on the store, and the app still crash, this error driving me crazy out, because i haven't on Xcode, the app never crashed to me, there is a way to caught it on Xcode? so I can see where is the error? I have also the .Crashlog file, but when I try to symbolicate it the terminal give me this:

```
atos cannot load symbols for the file MyApp for architecture armv7s.
```

anyone can help me please?

**EDIT in response to Philip Comment:**

in my `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` I do this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[BWQuincyManager sharedQuincyManager] setSubmissionURL:@"myserver"];
    [[BWQuincyManager sharedQuincyManager] startManager];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"FirstStart"] boolValue]) {

        WelcomeViewController_iPhone *welcome;
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {

            welcome = [[WelcomeViewController_iPhone alloc] initWithNibName:@"WelcomeViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];

        } else {
            welcome = [[WelcomeViewController_iPhone alloc] initWithNibName:@"WelcomeViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
        }

        [self.window setRootViewController:welcome];
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        return YES;
    }

    [self initiateAllViewWithFlag:NO];

    return YES;
}

- (void)initiateAllViewWithFlag:(BOOL)firstStart
{
    ...

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {

        self.tabBarController = [[AKTabBarController alloc] initWithTabBarHeight:49 position:AKTabBarPositionBottom];
        ...

    } else {

        self.tabBarController = [[AKTabBarController alloc] initWithTabBarHeight:63 position:AKTabBarPositionLeft];
        ...
    }

    [self.window setRootViewController:self.tabBarController];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    if (!firstStart) {
        [MTZWhatsNew handleWhatsNew:^(NSDictionary *whatsNew) {
            // Creating the view controller with features.
            MTZWhatsNewGridViewController *vc = [[MTZWhatsNewGridViewController alloc] initWithFeatures:whatsNew];

            // Presenting the what's new view controller.
            [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
        }];
    } else {
        [MTZWhatsNew setLastAppVersion:[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you put the code that you posted?  (In what method and class?)

Comment: i have putted in a lot of viewWillAppear of my UIViewController to see if there is something rootViewController not setted, and i have put a breakpoint in the IF condition, and is never called, so i think there is no rootViewController not setted

Comment: how i can fix an error that never never never happen to me on Xcode?

Comment: Set the root view controller in your app delegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.  That's what it means by "end of application launch".  (I assume you're not using a storyboard.)

Comment: @PhillipMills i have edited my question, you see something wrong in my code? (the question regarding why i can't reproduce this error on my device or on the simulator remain, if you can help me also with that)

Comment: Check whether `self.window` already points to a valid `UIWindow` when you enter the method.  It seems a little odd if you have to `alloc` a new one.  (Why it's different sometimes, I don't know...unless it's related to running with the debugger.)

Comment: Thanks for the help, i have found another UIWindow of another 3rd library that doesn't have setted the rootviewcontroller

Comment: I have exactly the same issue!!! Impossible to reproduce but I am seeing a lot of crash. Not sure I understand the workaround?